# How to deserialize json with unknown properties using JMS Serializer?

Tags: php, json, symfony, jms

I'm trying to create DTO which will help me to deserialize nested JSON. I know the structure of JSON but on some nested step I don't know the names/indexes of JSON properties.

JSON looks like:

```
{
  "project": {
    "layer": {
      "480x960": [],
      "720x360": [],
      "...": [],
      "...": []
    }
  }
}
```

but I don't know names of properties inside the *layer* property.

I have some DTOs so far

**Project DTO:**

```
namespace App\DTO;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

class Project
{
    /**
     * @var Layer
     *
     * @Serializer\Type("App\DTO\Layer")
     */
    protected $layer;
}
```

**Layer DTO:** (which I stuck on)

```
namespace App\DTO;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

class Layer
{
    // ???
}
```

I seek to achieve something like: **$project->getLayer()** will return Collection of objects *['480x960', '720x360', '...', etc.]*. I don't bother to keep names/indexes of those unknown properties inside *layer*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You don't need class for Layer.

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

class Project
{
    /**
     * @Serializer\Type("array<string, array>")
     */
    protected $layer;
}
```

Check http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/vsb9/mapping-random-json-and-xml-request-properties-with-jmsserializerbundle-in-symfony

Comment: Thank you for your time but it's not what I want to achieve. I must keep class for Layer because I want deserialize layer and other nested levels too.
I've tried your way before, even with `@Serializer\Type("array<string, App\DTO\Element>")` (Element class is one element of Layer) but also didn't work.
I had to do in a nasty way and split deserializing into 2 steps. First is what I have before Layer plus read available Layer's sizes, then second is `foreach` through all sizes.
Anyway I'm still waiting for more clever idea.